# What is the noun for "committable"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I am coding a program and want to raise a signal whenever the data of a form is in a state that allows it to be committed to a storage.

> signal committabilityChanged();

However, I don't find the word *committability* in the dictionaries I checked. Is committability a word? Else, what is the noun form of “committable”?

Comment: This isn't an English usage question but a computer-speak question. Why not ask a computer programmer? I vote to close.

Comment: Not every possibility of allowable  prefix and suffix combinations is in any dictionary. Your word seems correctly constructed to me.

Comment: @BillFranke i am using the english language in my computer program's code. how is it then not an english usage question?

Comment: Only programmers know the answer, not linguists or usage mavens. It's professional jargon, not English. I know a lot of biomedical jargon (that's my field) that looks like English but isn't: strictly professional jargon and no English usage expert  or linguist without knowledge of the jargon would be able to answer questions about correct usage. Even biomed pros in one specialty don't know how to use the jargon of other specialties. That's what makes it **not English**.

Comment: @BillFranke no, this is *entirely independent* of whether you are a programmer or not. i am searching for the noun form of "commit", nothing else. Why do you think you need to be a programmer for this? We do not program new words, unfortunately. They already exist. And "commit" is an everyday's use word, by far not only a programmers-word. I can't count the occasions I read "... did commit suicide".

Comment: What Mitch said in his comment. Just because it's not in the dictionary doesn't mean that you can't construct it using the standard rules of creating words. In any case, it won't be English even if you do because it's in a function statement in some programming language or other. Only a programmer can understand that "language". It's meaningless to me and has the same relationship to English that kitsch has to art. That's just reality.

Comment: @BillFranke i could aswell have asked my question "I am writing a book about suicides and I want to know the noun for 'commit' because I want to describe situations where a suicide may succeed. I tried 'committability of suicides', but this word cannot be found anywhere". this is the same question, but with another background information given. that doesn't suddenly make it a "book authors question" belonging on litature.SE.

Comment: @BillFranke if i would have asked 'what is the correct word for this signal? I tried "committabilityChanged" but it sounds weird', you would be right that it is a computer speak question. but I did not ask that.

Comment: No, it makes it an English question because then it's a book about suicide, which is a general topic understandable to average human beings. OTOH, the 'committability of suicides' is an obtuse expression that needs to be defined. Prima facie, it's absurd. People commit suicide. Why would you want to say something like "The committability of suicide is becoming easier and easier these days because nobody believes in eternal damnation as punishment for this mortal sin"? You'd say "It's becoming easier to commit suicide these days because..." That's English.

Comment: @BillFranke you again fall into the trap of discussing the background "the committability" vs "becoming easier to commit". That is *not* what is being asked. Perhaps that is one of the reasons you believe that this is a programming question?

Comment: @BillFranke:  Consider this:  How do psychiatrists evaluate a person's `committability` before making a recommendation for that person to be committed?

Comment: @oosterwal: Good question. I'm not a shrink, but I know that it all depends on context. There are guidelines, but they aren't easily available to the general public. Nor are the criteria for diagnosing mental illnesses, unless you have access to the DSM & understand the jargon. I understand some of it but not all of it. In any case, this discussion must come to an end. Jargon isn't normal idiomatic English. Period. End of discussion.

Comment: This question should stay open. It does not run afoul of the prohibition of questions about "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes", which has to do with questions that essentially ask "what should I name this variable" and are therefore much too subjective and open-ended. This question asks about a word's established noun form. The OP and others have done the research to show that this is also not a general reference question.

Answer (score 3):

[This Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=commitability,committability&year_start=1900&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) suggests that both *committability* and *commitability* are used, with the former being preferred over the latter. Their usage appears to be quite rare and specialised. Initially, *committability* seems to have been used primarily in the field of psychiatry. Later years show its increasing usage in computer books [as evidenced here](http://books.google.com/books?id=gbP1bLDPKlYC&pg=PA91&dq=%22committability%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D9bmUI6GIc6ukgW7moGQAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22committability%22&f=false).

Comment: And who reads computer books for fun? Certainly not literary types.

Comment: @BillFranke According to psychiatrists, those who don't are the ones who tend to satisfy most of the criteria for committability :)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Those who don't succeed can be committed. That is understandable English. I know what it means to be committed. One of my former girlfriends was committed for slashing her wrists. I was young and not in the biomed field then, but the word was a normal English word.

Comment: In any case, I'm just expressing my insignificant opinion about a the appropriateness of a question for EL&U. The Q doesn't need defending unless at least four other users here agree with me. I doubt that that will happen. Methinks the programmer doth protest too much! (8-O

Answer (score 3):

"[Committable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/committable)" was listed in the 1913 Webster's dictionary as an adjective.  There's no reason to assume that the noun form of this word, "committability," meaning "the quality of being committable" or "suitability to be committed," is invalid or grammatically incorrect.

For comparison see "[commutable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commutable)" and "[commutability](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commutability)."

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to use "commissible"/"commissibility", which is also not a word. "Committable"/"commitability" sounds fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

The term ***commitability*** is has already been defined and applied in respect of transactions in literature in related fields. See for example,

> ...the semantics of the *commit* operation. The **[commitability](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=1TkTsx_lfzMC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=define%20commitability&source=bl&ots=752yyBLluO&sig=jCkWAT1sCBwaA6pqJK0gN-ANhfs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ihvpUKKlCMKIrAeW8oHwAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=define%20commitability&f=false)** predicate plays an important role in defining the preconditions for this operation. A transaction t<sub>1</sub> is allowed to commit if all transactions t<sub>2</sub> that it depends on causally have committed, or are trying to commit. ...
>   *Formal Methods for Open Object-Based Distributed Systems IV* By Scott F. Smith, Carolyn L. Talcott

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are looking for the noun *commitment*.

Comment: That's a noun representing something actually *being* committed, not something being *able* to be committed.

Comment: No, the question is not looking for that. And this is a comment and not an answer, you should convert it.